# Can not pass date to nivo line chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, object, nivo-slider

I am using a nivo line chart and want to use the x-Axis as a timeline, down to a minute. 
Unfortunatelly I can not render that chart because it fails to read the date properly. For example this is part of my data:

```
{ x: "2020-04-24T13:07:44.000+0000", y: 0.8063946735624102 }
```

this is the data the chart gets, generated with the following code:

```
let cpuEntry = {
             x: data[i].created,
             y: data[i].system_cpu
         };
```

When I try to open the chart I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: v.getTime is not a function
```

After a bit of research I found out, the chart needs a Date obejct. I wrapped it like this:

```
x: new Date(data[i].created),
```

which gives me a result like this:

```
Fri Apr 24 2020 15:07:44 GMT+0200
```

and this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Apr 24 2020 15:25:00 GMT+0200). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is part of my configuration in the ResponsiveLine:

```
                    xScale={{
                    format: 'native',
                    type: 'time'
                }}
```

I have read something about trying to use "toString()" but thats just a circle of the same errors. I hope someone can help me. If needed I will provide further information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should to specify xScale format as

```
xScale={{ format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z", type: "time" }}
```

And xFormat (as an example)

```
xFormat="time:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z"
```

Or (if you want just time)

```
xFormat="time:%H:%M:%S.%L"
```

Also based on your time intervals you can set `axisBottom` settings as follow:

```
axisBottom={{
          tickValues: "every 1 second",
          tickSize: 5,
          tickPadding: 5,
          tickRotation: 0,
          format: "%S.%L",
          legend: "Time",
          legendOffset: 36,
          legendPosition: "middle"
        }}
```

Here is a complete working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-dbr34?file=/src/index.js

And for time formats refer to https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Comment: In combination with the axisBottom settings in the example it worked parfectly fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: After configuring axisBottom, it works for me I am using nivo 0.80.0. Setting axisBottom with format and "Time" legend is very important. Without it, nothing is rendered (blank white rectangle).